# Cannot figure out rigid bodies. Can anyone help?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to learn rigid body physics in Blender. I setup a simple test enviroment with two cubes and a plane and am trying to get the cubes to get one cube to push the other cube respectively. I have both objects set to mesh, deform, and animate, just as it says on all of the tutorials where it looks so simple. But, nothing ever happens no matter what I do. I have tried applying all transforms to everything. Can anyone take a look at the file and tell me what I need to do? I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfvjqytjbg8e8p6/RigidTest.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work. Some how removing the default rigid body world and applying a new one did the trick, along with unchecking the animated box for the object being pushed.

Comment: Sometimes realizing that the blender user guide is very incomplete, pulling out all your hair, and throwing salt over your shoulder helps!

Answer (score 1):

Things to change:

1. In your Scene Properties, change Collection to "Rigid Body World" by left-mouse inside the Collection
2. In your Scene Properties, clear the Constraints collection.
3. Remove all your Rigid Body Constaints (perhaps the ones with no Obj-1, Obj-2 are useless, I'm not sure)